# &amp code javascript are not being replaced with &

Tags: javascript, replace

My code:

```
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+urlToShare+"&amp;"+"t="+"test","_blank", "width=700, height=400");
```

On the resulting URL '*&amp;*' should be replaced with '*&*', right? But, it isn't being replaced.

Comment: actually it should be on "&" but I think the interpreter automatically replaced it with &

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

An `&` which you want to express as data in an HTML document should (with a few exceptions such as being inside a `<script>` or when followed by a space) be expressed as `&amp;`. It will then be interpreted by the browser as `&` after the HTML is parsed.

In this case, you have JavaScript (which is not HTML) and a URL (which is also not HTML) so there is no HTML to parse so the HTML parsing rules that would read `&amp;` as `&` do not apply.

Comment: Ok. So what should I do? My function is inside a html document so when I open the html document it gives me error. Should I move it for another file and then use just _&_?

Comment: @Chittolina - Just use `&` instead of `&amp;` when building the URL string.

Comment: @Oriol — And explicitly defined as containing CDATA (in HTML 4 terms) so character references are not expanded.

Comment: @Chittolina — What error? What context are you using it in?

Comment: @Quentin Exactly. I misread your answer, sorry, I thought it said the HTML parser doesn't parse the contents of `script` elements due to JS not being HTML.

Comment: I wrote the function inside an XSL document of a DSpace theme. the error I'm getting is that:
SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow 
                   the '&' in the entity reference

Comment: @Chittolina — The context of "being inside XSL" is very, very important. The question just shows JavaScript.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry about that and I just fixed the problem. I put the function inside a CDATA section and defined the script tag as a javascript and it's now working. Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

Not in HTML. [Character references](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) are not allowed everywhere:

> In certain cases described in other sections, text may be mixed with
>   character references.

When the HTML parser [finds a `<script>` tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#scriptTag), it switches the tokenizer to the [script data state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#script-data-state).

Unlike the [data state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#data-state), the script data state doesn't have character references.

So just use `&` instead of `&amp;`.

```
<!-- This is HTML -->
<script>
alert('&');
</script>
```

---

However, you would need `&amp;` in XHTML, because in XML the parser doesn't have different behaviors depending on the element.

```
<!-- This is XHTML -->
<script>
alert('&amp;');
</script>
```

But using `&amp;` in JS code is undesirable, so you can wrap the code in a [CDATA section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#cdata-sections)

```
<!-- This is XHTML -->
<script><![CDATA[
alert('&');
]]></script>
```